# Using ImageOptim for *lossless* PNG optimization results in different color images

Tags: optimization, image-compression, image-optimization

Google's PageSpeed tool told me to optimize my PNG images, which were saved for web in Photoshop. After researching lossless PNG compression options I downloaded ImageOptim and put a few images through it. The results have vastly different colors than the originals, which seems to indicate that this compression is actually lossy. Any suggestions?

Original image:

[image: Original image]

After ImageOptim:

[image: After ImageOptim]

Comment: Those images look pretty similar to me... which colors are you seeing differently?

Comment: yeah i guess it depends on the screen. on my phone they are the same but not on my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Your image has embedded color profile, which for web is very wasteful and a compatibility headache.

For the web always export images in sRGB color, with no embedded profile, gamma 2.2.

http://imageoptim.com/color-profiles.html

Comment: That's strange because I did click "convert to sRGB" before saving in Photoshop. I guess I'll try again.